# How to split attached files created by aggregator

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

I have a bunch of related PDF and XML files in an input folder:

```
1.PDF - 1.XML
2.PDF - 2.XML
3.PDF - 3.XML
etc.
```

The PDF file is a scanned document, and the related XML file contains indexing information related to the PDF file.

I use Apache Camel to poll the folder for XML and PDF files, which I then release to an output folder as soon as I have a releated pair. Ideally I would like to release the XML file last.

The following code seems to pick up the pair correctly, but I get an error message when I try to split the files again.

```
@Grab('org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.13.0')
@Grab('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.6')
import org.apache.camel.*
import org.apache.camel.impl.*
import org.apache.camel.builder.*
import org.apache.camel.util.jndi.*

def jndiContext = new JndiContext();

def dataDir = "/${System.properties['user.home']}/test/file-poller-demo"
def camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(jndiContext)
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    def void configure() {
    from("file://${dataDir}/in")
        .aggregate(simple('${file:onlyname.noext}')).completionSize(2).groupExchanges()
        .split(body())
        .to("file://${dataDir}/out")
}
})
camelContext.start()
addShutdownHook{ camelContext.stop() }
synchronized(this){ this.wait() }
```

Error message:

> No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: Exchange[1.xml] of type: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange on: 1.txt. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value Exchange[1.xml]. Exchange[1.txt].

Answer (score 1):

The following are working examples in Java DSL.

You can add an extra processor to set the correct output body after the exchange is aggregated but without noop=true option in the file consumer  the first file will be moved to .camel after the aggregation and the file producer will throw an expression when it tries to write it to the outbox folder.

```
from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
        .aggregate(simple("${file:onlyname.noext}")).completionSize(2).groupExchanges()
        .split(body())
        .process(new Processor() {
         @Override
         public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Exchange exchangeIn = exchange.getIn().getBody(Exchange.class);
            exchange.getIn().setBody(exchangeIn.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class));
            exchange.getIn().setHeaders(exchangeIn.getIn().getHeaders());
         }
         })
         .to("file:data/outbox/");
```

I believe is it better to load the files in an in memory datastore and aggregate afterwards.

In the following route, after the file is consumed it is added in an in-memory datastore. After the aggregation is comleted the files are retrieved from the datastore in the splitter and the datastore is cleared in the last exchange. The delete option in the file consumer is optional. If not added the files will be moved to .camel after completion.

```
from("file:data/inbox?delete=true")
.setProperty("correlationId", simple("${file:onlyname.noext}"))
.beanRef("dataStoreBean","addToStore")
.aggregate(property("correlationId")).completionSize(2).groupExchanges()
.split(body())
.beanRef("dataStoreBean", "getFromStore")
.to("file:data/outbox/");
```

Where the datastore bean is:

```
public class DataStoreBean {

    Map<String,byte[]> dataStore = new HashMap<String,byte[]>();

    public void addToStore(Exchange exchange) {
        dataStore.put(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,StrinTheg.class),exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class));
        exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,String.class));
    }

     public void getFromStore(Exchange exchange) {
    Exchange fileExchange = exchange.getIn().getBody(Exchange.class);
    String fileName = fileExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, fileName);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(dataStore.get(fileName));
    if(exchange.getProperty("CamelSplitComplete", Boolean.class)) {
        String correlationId = fileExchange.getProperty("correlationId", String.class);
        dataStore.remove(correlationId+".pdf");
        dataStore.remove(correlationId+".xml");
    }
}
}
```